# Gulp: How to build only one directory from project

Tags: angularjs, build, gulp

I Have project in webstorm which I already run gulp build on it several times, in order to build all the project.

[image]

Now, I want to build **only** the wordCloud directory. how to do that ? 
As you can see from the screenshot, The structure of the application is directive and service, and the module file is in wbxWordCloud.js :

```
import {wordService} from './word.service.js';
import {wbxWordCloud} from './wbxWordCloud.directive.js';

angular.module('wbxWordCloud', [])
  .service('wordService', wordService)
  .directive('wbxWordCloud', wbxWordCloud);
```

gulp.js file:

```js
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function() {
  return gulp.src([
      path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
      path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
    ])
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'untitled1',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function() {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), {
    read: false
  });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', {
    restore: true
  });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', {
    restore: true
  });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', {
    restore: true
  });

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    //.pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/material-design-iconfont/iconfont/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe($.rev())
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({
      title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'),
      showFiles: true
    }));
});

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles().concat('bower_components/material-design-iconfont/iconfont/*'))
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,otf,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function() {
  var fileFilter = $.filter(function(file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
  });

  return gulp.src([
      path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
      path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js}')
    ])
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

Comment: I afraid this have nothing to do with webstorm. It;s about gulp settings and without provided usefull data I afraid we can't do much

Comment: I edit and added the relevant data

Comment: Have you tired adding a filer to the task like: `var somefilter = $.filter('**/WordCloud/**/*', { restore: true });` I'm gussing it would work but it's a bigger project and I can't really test it.

Comment: Trying to understand: So you want to run the `build` task as is, and then run it again but using different `gulp.src`s and different `gulp.dest`s in all the called tasks?